# How to match JSON Values and put the data in respective Columns in SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, dictionary, multidimensional-array, swift3, multiple-columns

Please look at the **JSON** given below.

I have to set `rollNumber` as rows and `subjects` as columns and put `marks` under respective subject column. Columns will contain all 5 subjects. 
Here is what I have done:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if case (1...(subjectsArray.count + 1), 1...(rollNoArray.count + 1)) = (indexPath.column, indexPath.row)
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: DataCell.self), for: indexPath) as! DataCell
let text = marksArrayTranspose[indexPath.column-1][indexPath.row - 1]

    if !text.isEmpty
    {
        cell.label.text = text
    }
    else {
        cell.label.text = "-"

    }
    return cell
}
return nil
}
```

I have taken transpose of marksArray which is of type [[Int]], but **OUTPUT** is the result I have got. I have to match the **subjects(keys of values)** given in `score` with the values of `subjects` array and then put the `marks` under respective subject column.Where there is no marks for a particular subject, there I have to put a  '-'(dash).Please suggest,how can I get Expected Output result.

**OUTPUT:**

```
      | Mathematics | English | Science | History | Geography |
---------------------------------------------------------------
100   |      82     |   90    |    80   |    -    |     -     |
101   |      95     |   78    |    89   |   82    |    80     |
102   |      74     |   81    |    71   |   68    |     -     |
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
      | Mathematics | English | Science | History | Geography |
---------------------------------------------------------------
100   |      -      |   82    |    90   |   80    |     -     |
101   |      95     |   78    |    89   |   82    |    80     |
102   |      74     |   81    |    71   |    -    |    68     |
```

The **UPDATED** JSON is as follows:

```
{
"subjects": [
  "Mathematics",
  "English",
  "Science",
  "History",
  "Geography"
],
"data": [
  {
    "rollNumber" : 100,
    "studentName": "Mary Alex"
  },
  {
    "rollNumber" : 101,
    "studentName": "John Smith"
  },
  {
    "rollNumber" : 102,
    "studentName": "Anna Brook"
  }
],
"score": {
  "100": {
    "English": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "82",
        "remark": "excellent"
    },
    "Science": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "90",
        "remark": "excellent"
      },
    "History": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "80",
        "remark": "excellent"
      }
  },
  "101": {
    "Mathematics": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "95",
        "remark": "excellent"
      },
    "English": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "78",
        "remark": "excellent"
      },
    "Science": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "89",
        "remark": "excellent"
      },
    "History": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "82",
        "remark": "excellent"
      },
    "Geography": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "80",
        "remark": "excellent"
      }
    },
  "102": {
    "Mathematics": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "74",
        "remark": "good"
      },
    "English": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "81",
        "remark": "excellent"
      },
    "Science": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "71",
        "remark": "good"
      },
    "Geography": {
        "status": "present",
        "marks" : "68",
        "remark": "satisfactory"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Code to parse JSON:

```
class Data: NSObject
{
var marksArray = [[String]]()
public required init(dictionary: [String : Any])
{ super.init()
if let dataValues = dictionary["score"] as? Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Any>>
{
    let sortedDataValues = dataValues.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
//  --------------- iterate over first dictionary  -------------------------
    for(key, value) in sortedDataValues
    {
        //  rollNumbers are keys of first Dict
        let rollNumber:String = key

        // subjects are keys of values of first Dict
        let subjects = value.sorted { $0.key > $1.key}
        let marks = subjects.flatMap() {$0.value}
        let subMarks = (marks as AnyObject).value(forKey: "marks")
        marksArray.append(subMarks as! [String])
    }
}}}
```

What I was thinking was to compare elements of subjectsArray and scoreSubjectsArray, find the index of uncommon elements and do `marksArray.insert("-", at: indexOfUncommonItem)`. But I don't know how to do that. Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Comment: What the code for parsing the JSON? The issue lies there.

Comment: @Larme   I have parsed the JSON in other class and called that in my DataViewController. To parse 'score' objects I have used nested for loops since it is Dictionary of Dictionaries. Next keys itself are values of previous keys so. That's what I thought of.

Comment: @Larme Please check the updated question. I have updated code to parse JSON

Comment: Are you getting the `JSON` from somewhere else? Or, are you handling the making of `JSON` by yourself? Because the `JSON` is so badly formatted.

Comment: @nayem I am given that JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some code to your Data object. Please try the following:

```
class Data: NSObject
{
    var marksArray = [[String]]()
    public required init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        super.init()
        let subjectsArray:[String] = dictionary["subjects"] as! [String]
        if let dataValues = dictionary["score"] as? Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Any>>
        {
            let sortedDataValues = dataValues.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
            //  --------------- iterate over first dictionary  -------------------------
            for(key, value) in sortedDataValues
            {
                //  rollNumbers are keys of first Dict
                let rollNumber:String = key

                // subjects are keys of values of first Dict
                var subjects = value.sorted { $0.key > $1.key}
                let subjectsKeys = subjects.map{$0.key}
                var x = 0
                for i in subjectsArray {
                    if !subjectsKeys.contains(i) {
                        subjects.insert((key: i, value: ["marks":"-"]), at: x)
                    }
                    x += 1
                }
                let marks = subjects.flatMap() {$0.value}
                let subMarks = (marks as AnyObject).value(forKey: "marks")
                marksArray.append(subMarks as! [String])
            }
        }
    }
}
```